# Get the value of a td by class and ID

Tags: jquery, html, class

I need to get the value of a td by both it's class and it's ID.
I have the following code at the moment, which doesn't seem to work.

```
for (a = 0; a < count; a++) 
     { 
         var warehouse = $('.warehousename #' + a).text();
         console.log(warehouse); 
     }
```

The TD code is as follows;

```
echo "<td class='warehousename' id='".$i."'>" . $array[$i]['warehouse'] . "</td>";
```

The i and a variable are correct.

Comment: `$('.warehousename#' + a).text();` remove the space in between and it should work

Comment: it stays empty unfortunately

Comment: If you have ID then no need of class selector.  Simple use ID selector like `$('#' + a).text()`

Comment: Looks like you are assigning the same id multiple time if you aim to use both the class and the id. ids must be unique on the all document.

Comment: @Raflesia it seems that your `id` is a number.  i dont know if its because it starts with a number. can you change the format of your `ID`?

Answer (score 2):

If your ID is not unique (but it shouldn't be so), you can use the following selector.

```
var warehouse = $('.warehousename#' + a).text();
```

And again: it **shouldn't be so**. HTML `id` attribute stands for **unique** identificator in HTML markup. If you want to set your warehouses' `id` to some tds for future use, you should use custom attributes.

For example, in PHP:

```
echo "<td class='warehousename' data-id='".$i."'>" . $array[$i]['warehouse'] . "</td>";
```

JS:

```
var warehouse = $('.warehousename[data-id="' + a + '"]').text();
```

It looks better and it is valid. 
With that approach you can assign numbers to `data-id`.
It would be incorrect in case of HTML `id` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Since ID of an element must be unique you could just say

```
var warehouse = $('#' + a).text();
```

Your selector `'.warehousename #' + a` looks for an element with the given id(value of `a`) which is a descendant of an element with class `warehousename`, but in your case the element itself have the class so it won't return any element